# Unable to run testng annotations in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

I was trying to understand the working of **testng** framework by implementing a simple program in Eclipse editor(in ubuntu os). My source code and pom xml are defined as follows:

**TestExample.java**

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test(suiteName = "test suite for annotation")
public class TestExample {


    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("before test");
    }


    @AfterSuite
    public void finish() {
        System.out.println("After test");
    }

    @Test(description = "Test to save student", priority = 0)
    public void testSaveStudent() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Testing.....");
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nithin.exmple</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestingExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

But on execution my Eclipse editor fails to give expected output (it is rendering an output of a program which I have run recently). I have executed the same program on IntelliJ IDE which in turn gives expected results.

Comment: Right-click on test class in Navigator panel and run it.

Comment: I have tried the same ... but i dont get any expected results.

Comment: Install TestNg plugin http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html

Comment: @Sergi That worked!! Post the above comment as answer so that I can accept and upvote.

Comment: @Nithin, good that it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install TestNg plugin - [testng.org/doc/eclipse.html](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html)

Comment: If long term Eclipse support is a concern, it may be relevant that junit support is in core Eclipse and testng isn't.

Comment: TestNG has many advantages over JUnit ( https://www.bugraptors.com/introduction-testng-framework-benefits-junit-framework/ ) and also some IDEs have TestNG as inbuilt plug-ins. But in case of eclipse it should be downloaded from market place